# Why is the "drop-down" part of a <select> tag not affected by CSS 2D transforms?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When using `transform: scale(...)` on a `div` with various elements in it, everything scales as expected except for the "drop-down" part of a `<select>` tag:

```js
function test() {
    alert("test");
}

let contentDiv = document.getElementById("contentDiv");
let scaleSlider = document.getElementById("scaleSlider");

console.log(contentDiv);
console.log(scaleSlider);

scaleSlider.oninput = function() {
  contentDiv.style = "transform: scale(" + this.value + ")";
};
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="1" value="1" step="0.1"
         class="slider" id="scaleSlider" style="direction: rtl">
  <div id="contentDiv">
    <button onclick="test()">test</button>
    <div style="background:green; width:100px; height:100px"></div>
    <label>some text</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="textInput"></input>
    <br />
    <select>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></img>
    <ul>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>
    <ol>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
    </ol>
    <progress value="22" max="100"></progress>
    <br />
    <svg width="100" height="100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    </svg>
    <br />
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
      At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies. 
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you change `scale` to `rotate`, you get similar results. It seems that the drop-down part of `<select>` is simply not affected by CSS 2D transforms.

Why is this? And is there any way around it? I'm looking to use CSS 2D transforms as a robust way of "per-element" zoom, but edge cases like this make me wary of the idea.

Answer (score -1):

The dropdown options are rendered by your operating system and you can not apply CSS properties to them (a couple trivial properties like `font-weight` are supported in some browsers). You can consider using third party libraries that resemble the select dropdown and apply CSS styles to them.

Check out [Select2](https://select2.org/dropdown) which is a good example of custom select.

Comment: Is there documentation on operating-system rendered elements somewhere? If this is going to be a nuance of using CSS 2D transforms, I would want to thoroughly investigate which edge cases I need to watch out for.

Comment: That's of course incorrect. The drop down is rendered by the browser. There's no "render a drop down" in the Linux kernel.

Comment: Sorry for my poor choice of words. The UI design for form elements are not defined in the specs, and it is up to the browser to decide how the dropdown will be rendered. If you look at barebones select's on a macOS(Safari/Firefox/Chrome) they are rendered consistently to match the macOS design look and feel. The similar thing applies for Windows and Linux. If you absolutely want to apply CSS styles consistently to your selects, writing a custom implementation is your only way. A good write up is here https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/